# How to make a commutative diagram using {tikz-cd}?

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I want to make a commutative diagram which looks like:

[image]

I tried the following code:

```
\begin{tikzcd}

A\arrow[r,"\phi_n"]  \arrow[d,swap,"\text{id}"]&

A_n  \arrow[dl,swap,"\psi_n"] \arrow[dr,"\pi_n"]\\

\mathbb{B}(H) && \mathbb{B}(H_n) 

\end{tikzcd}
```

This gave me a portion of the diagram. How do I get the other half?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Think to a matrix and add the arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge]
A \arrow[r,"\phi_n"] \arrow[d,swap,"\pi"] &
A_n \arrow[r,"\epsilon_{i,n}"] \arrow[dl,swap,"\psi_n"] \arrow[dr,"\pi_n"] &
M_{n_k}(\mathbb{C}) \arrow[d,"\eta_{i,n}"]
\\
B(H) & & B(H_n) \arrow[ll,dashed]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]